# Is it possible to put the '\vdots' in a sympy.Matrix?

Tags: python, symbols

This latex

```
\begin{bmatrix}x_i^{(1)} \\ \vdots\\ x_i^{(m)}\end{bmatrix}
```

generates this equation (equation_1)

[image]

this sympy code

```
xi1 = Symbol('x_i^{(1)}')
xidots = Symbol('\dots')
xim = Symbol('x_i^{(m)}')
Matrix([xi1, xidots, xim])
```

generates this equation (equation_2) in latex

[image]

`Symbol('\vdots')` does not give a vertical dots like the one in equation_1

Is it possible to put the '\vdots' in a sympy.Matrix?

Comment: For those debugging, there is an [online shell here](https://live.sympy.org/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use double backslash (`\\vdots`)

```
xi1 = Symbol('x_i^{(1)}')
xidots = Symbol('\\vdots')
xim = Symbol('x_i^{(m)}')
Matrix([xi1, xidots, xim])
```

[image]